# Adding time to VBA macro returns different date format despite range formatting

Tags: date, formatting, regional-settings

Vba swaps date and month despite formatting when entering using 'Date'-function

**What I'm trying to do**
I am trying to return todays date and a specific time in a cell. Let's say today is 01/06/2023. I'm from Europe so this means June 1st 2023.
E.g Upon activating the macro cell A10 must return: **01/06/2023 22:00:00**

**For this I have written the following code:**

```
Range("A10").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
Range("A10").Value = Date & "22:00:00"
```

When activating the macro the cell returned: **01/06/202322:00:00**

However my formulas can't use this cell as there is no space between the date and time I added a space in the time-string

**So the formula became:**

```
Range("A10").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
Range("A10").Value = Date & " 22:00:00"
```

So the only difference is the space between the quoatation mark and 22:00:00.
Unfortunately it returns:** 06/01/2023 22:00:00** despite formatting the range in dd/mm/yyyy. The extra characters changes the date format.

**What I've also tried**
**The following formula:**

```
Range("A10").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
Range("A10").Value = Date & " " & " 22:00:00"
```

But this gave the same result unfortunately.

**Important detail:**
When using only the date function (so without & "22:00:00"), the date is returned in the correct format. So only the addition of the time seems to change the format

Anybody knows what it is I'm doing wrong?

**Other things I tried**:
As an alternative I added the date (in the correct format) and time intwo adjecent cells and used the concatenate function. And had VBA copy it to the cell I want. However VBA copies the formula and not the value. So if anybody knows a way to copy the formula value instead of the formula itself via VBA that would also help.

Thanks in advance.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code:

```
Range("A10").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
Range("A10").Value = Date + CDate("22:00:00")
```